# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to (...)\Handler\FlightHandler::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form

Tags: symfony

I have a big bug, who just take 2 hours of my time...
I have changed the configureOptions method in my FlightType, but it was not the solution.

The error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Test\FrontBundle\Form\Handler\FlightHandler::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form, none given, called in
>   /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Projets
>   Web/Emirates/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 834
>   and defined

I 've just coded my service.yml like that :

```
services:
    flight_form:
        factory_service: form.factory
        factory_method: createNamed
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments:
            - flight
            - flight_form

    flight_type:
        class: Test\FrontBundle\Form\Type\FlightType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: flight_form }

    flight_handler:
        class: Test\FrontBundle\Form\Handler\FlightHandler
        argument: [@flight_form, @request]
        scope: request
```

> FlightController.php

```
        public function createAction(Request $request) {


            $formHandler = $this->get("flight_handler");
            $form = $formHandler->getForm();

            if ($formHandler->process()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($form->getData());
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("test_front_flight_list"));
            }

            return $this->render('TestFrontBundle:Flight:create.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

        }
    }
```

> FlightHandler.php

```
(...)

class FlightHandler {

    protected $form;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request) {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getForm() {
        return $this->form;
    }

    public function process() {

        $this->form->handleRequest($this->request);

        if ($this->request->isMethod("POST") && $this->form->isValid()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

> FlightType.php

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    /** @var OptionResolver $resolver */
    $this->configureOptions($resolver);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        "data_class" => 'Test\FrontBundle\Entity\Flight'
    ));
```

Comment: I see you use `flight_form`in three different ways: first you define a service called `flight_form`. Then you say that one of the arguments to this service is `flight_form`. Finally you say that `flight_form`is an alias for the `flight_type` service. This is all very confusing. I suggest you clear this up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK. In my service.yml, at the end, "argument" must be "arguments"